# How To check the data type of some data in a textBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the part  that I start taking data from text boxes but I want to chek it  datatype at 1st
Ex: in text box 4 if the text box has  letters in it  show message "Error please  enter Numbers only " 
Ex: in text box number 1 if the text box has numbers in it>> show error message" Error please enter Letters only" and so on

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    dr = ds.Tables["Employees"].NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = textBox1.Text;           
    dr["E-Mail"] = textBox2.Text;
    dr["Age"] = textBox4.Text;
    dr["WorkHours"] = textBox5.Text;
    dr["Gender"] = textBox6.Text;
    dr["JobTitle"] = textBox3.Text;
    ds.Tables["Employees"].Rows.Add(dr);
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter("Data.xml"))
    {
        ds.WriteXml(sw);
        sw.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You would have received a quicker response by searching C# data validation textbox in google: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'd add that in many cases where you think you want alpha only, you actually should allow alphanumeric input. For example, in Name, you should allow "Se7en" (in case someone was named after the rapper), or "John Smith 2nd", or "La-a" (pronounced Ladasha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `int.TryParse(string, int)` like

```
     int number;
     bool result = Int32.TryParse(textbox4.Text, out number);
```

Comment: Thank You  it worked  :D